# How to minimize the error to a given dataset

Tags: python, optimization, mathematical-optimization

lets assume a function

```
f(x,y) = z
```

Now I want to choose x so that the output of f matches real data, and y decreases in equidistant steps to zero starting from 1. The output is calculated in the function f by a set of differential equations.

How can I select x so that the error to the real outputs is as small as possible. Assuming I know a set of z - values, namely

```
f(x,1) = z_1
f(x,0.9) = z_2
f(x,0.8) = z_3
```

now find `x`, that the error to the real data `z_1,z_2,z_3` is minimal.
How can one do this?

Comment: Your function makes no sense. x doesn't appear on the right-hand side, hence is irrelevant to the minimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common method of optimizing is least squares fitting, in which you would basically try to find params such that the sum of squares: `sum (f(params,xdata_i) - ydata_i))^2` is minimized for given `xdata` and `ydata`. In your case: `params` would be `x`, `xdata_i` would be 1, 0.9 and 0.8 and `ydata_i` z_1, z_2 and z_3.

You should consider the package scipy.optimize. It's used in finding parameters for a function. I think [this page](https://python4mpia.github.io/fitting_data/least-squares-fitting.html) gives quite a good example on how to use it.